# error: invalid use of template-name ‘boost::asio::strand’ without an argument list

Tags: c++, boost

**When I compiled C++ code with cmake and boost 1.64.0, a `boost:: ASIO:: strand` error occurred.My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.
Here is my C++ Code:**

```
#pragma once
// This file and the associated implementation has been placed in the public domain, waiving all copyright. No restrictions are placed on its use. 
#include "Common/Defines.h"
#include <deque>
#include <mutex>
#include <future> 
#include "Network/BtIOService.h"
namespace osuCrypto { 
    class WinNetIOService;
    class ChannelBuffer;


    class BtSocket
    {
    public:
        BtSocket(BtIOService& ios);

        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket mHandle;
        boost::asio::strand mSendStrand, mRecvStrand;   //Error line

        std::deque<BoostIOOperation> mSendQueue, mRecvQueue;
        bool mStopped;

        std::atomic<u64> mOutstandingSendData, mMaxOutstandingSendData, mTotalSentData, mTotalRecvData;
    };


}
```

ERROR infomation:

```
In file included from /root/project/MultipartyPSI/MultipartyPSI/cryptoTools/Network/BtAcceptor.h:8:0,
                 from /root/project/MultipartyPSI/MultipartyPSI/cryptoTools/Network/BtEndpoint.h:5,
                 from /root/project/MultipartyPSI/MultipartyPSI/frontend/OtBinMain.cpp:1:
/root/project/MultipartyPSI/MultipartyPSI/cryptoTools/Network/BtSocket.h:76:9: error: invalid use of template-name ‘boost::asio::strand’ without an argument list
         boost::asio::strand mSendStrand, mRecvStrand;
         ^~~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

**If you have any original views on this problem, please help me.**

Comment: As the message says, `boost::asio::strand` is a template, not a type. Did you not read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

When  i use `boost::asio::io_service::strand` the error no longer occurs。
For the documented interface changes see: [Networking TS compatibility](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/net_ts.html#:%7E:text=This%20template%20works%20with%20any%20valid%20executor%2C%20and%20is%20itself%20a%20valid%20executor)

Comment: Did you... really not acknowledge my answer at all, instead taking a link from it and providing the legacy fall-back option from it? Oh well. Keep in mind that `io_service` is deprecated, and so is `io_service::strand`

Answer (score 0):

The interface for strands changed.

The simplest approach here will be to change `strand` into `any_io_executor` which can hold ... any executor, including a strand.

```
boost::asio::any_io_executor mSendStrand, mRecvStrand;
```

> *There exists a very small window of Boost releases where `any_io_executor` didn't exist, but `strand<>` was already a template. In that case I expect that `boost::asio::executor` is available with the same semantics as current `any_io_executor`.*

For the documented interface changes see: [Networking TS compatibility](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/net_ts.html#:%7E:text=This%20template%20works%20with%20any%20valid%20executor%2C%20and%20is%20itself%20a%20valid%20executor)

Comment: In case you're using an open source project like https://github.com/osu-crypto/MultipartyPSI/ consider updating to their latest version and seeing whether they have a branch/PR that addresses these issues.